# Unable to update "Snap Store": cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has running apps (ubuntu-software)

Tags: updates, software-center, snap, 22.04, snap-store

I am a new Ubuntu 22.04 user who is facing an issue with the Snap
Store. Whenever I try to update the Snap Store I can see these error messages.

[image]

```
Pending update of "snap-store" snap 
Close the app to avoid disruptions (13 days left)
```

[image: error 2]

```
Unable to update "Snap Store": 
(null): cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has 
running apps (ubuntu-software)
```

Comment: I'm amazed that there is no better answer for this.

Answer (score 238, accepted):

Sometimes the snap-store process starts in the background and stays open with 0% CPU usage even if the user did not actually launch the Snap Store application in the current session. For example, this would be the case if the following notification appeared on your desktop one or two minutes after booting Ubuntu.

[image]

If you opened the System Monitor it would show that the snap-store process had started automatically and was running. Ending the snap-store process would enable you to update the snap-store by running the following command, or alternatively a notification would appear that the snap-store has been updated would appear immediately after the snap-store process was ended.

```
sudo snap refresh
```

Alternatively to end the snap-store process so that the snap-store snap can be updated run the following command.

```
snap-store --quit && sudo snap refresh snap-store
```

If `snap-store --quit` doesn't work then force end the snap-store process from the System Monitor and run `sudo snap refresh snap-store`.

After the snap-store has been refreshed you may receive a notification in the notification area next to the clock that says `"snap-store" snap has been refreshed. Now available to launch.`

[image]

Comment: Thanks! When I ran this command, I propted that snap-store was running, so I kill them and try again like: `sudo killall snap-store && sudo snap refresh`

Comment: Needed the System Monitor version - killall snap didn't capture the snap-store app. All updated now - Thx

Comment: Be careful with copy paste, you could update everything. Which could be not intended. Use this `sudo killall snap && sudo snap refresh snap-store`.

Comment: @koralgooll Edited. Thank you.

Comment: This command worked to me: `sudo killall snap-store && sudo snap refresh snap-store`

Comment: I think it should be `pkill`

Comment: Thanks! It works.

Comment: karel, thanks so much!!! ```sudo pkill snap-store && sudo snap refresh snap-store``` is what did the trick for me.

Comment: `pkill` s a bit over the top, you can use `snap-store --quit` to make it stop gracefully.

Comment: This works but the problem keeps reappearing with each snap-store update. Is there a way resolve this permanently?

Comment: @Calimo The way resolve this problem permanently is by performing all software updates via the terminal. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1290308/) shows how to rerun any command in your bash history by typing one or two keys. This makes it much easier to use the terminal.

Comment: While running `snap-store --quit && sudo snap refresh snap-store` I encountered `error: snap "snap-store" has "auto-refresh" change in progress` so I waited a minute, then reopened `snap-store` (Ubuntu Software) to see on the Updates tab the friendly Up To Date screen, hooray!

Answer (score 56):

I had the same problem with a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

The accepted answer did not work for me, so I solved with:

```
$ sudo killall snap-store
$ sudo snap refresh snap-store
```

Comment: I had to do the `sudo snap refresh snap-store` to get it refreshed.
Thanks

Comment: This worked for me when Snap updater was complaining Snap was running.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Comment: After those commands snap-store can be restarted with `snap run snap-store &`

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me, Thank you!

Comment: That is the correct answer. Isn't there a community feature to correct "accepted answer" somehow?

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem and managed to solve it today removing the snap-store with:

```
sudo snap remove snap-store
```

and then re-installing it with:

```
sudo snap install snap-store
```

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: It's the only brute force that worked for me. It suppressed some packages. Hope no harm done. By Jove, it is quite disgracious, I say!

Comment: If you have to go to Google to figure out how to do something like this, the product needs improvement...

Answer (score 3):

In my case there is pids show up

```
$ sudo snap refresh snap-store
error: cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has running apps (snap-store), pids: 3452
$ kill 3452
$ sudo snap refresh snap-store
snap-store 41.3-71-g709398e from Canonical✓ refreshed
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the issue above and other related snap-store [bugs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469200/how-can-i-dismiss-software-updates-installed-notification/) and [failings](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/pending-update-of-snap-store-but-no-update-available/34415), a couple of months ago I removed snap-store:

```
snap remove snap-store
```

This leaves the snap system intact, but just removes the troublesome snap-store.

Instead I now use gnome-software which manages snaps perfectly without any of the above issues. gnome-software also has the advantage that it handles flatpak and DEB packages.