# Can't update or uninstall preinstalled applications from the Ubuntu Software

Tags: updates, software-center, uninstall

I installed Ubuntu a few hours ago and I can't update or uninstall any preinstalled apps from the Ubuntu Software shop. I have tried to restart my computer and uninstall-reinstall the shop via the terminal, as seen from another question here. Nothing worked. When trying to uninstall system apps like Mahjongg I get the error: Unable to remove : no packages to remove. When I try to update an app like Snap Store I get: Unable to update : (null): cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has runing apps (ubuntu-software), pids 2082. What can I do?

Comment: What leads you to believe that Mahjong is installed?

Comment: Updating Snap Store is a bad example; that's the one application that cannot be updated from within Snap Store (Ubuntu Software). Snaps cannot (currently) be updated while running. Pick a different example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to update "Snap Store": cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has running apps (ubuntu-software)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411104/unable-to-update-snap-store-cannot-refresh-snap-store-snap-snap-store-ha)

Comment: Nothing helped. I reinstalled Ubuntu since, I had my data safe in a backup.