# If I disable snap store does that affect installed apps?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, software-center, snap

I am fairly new to Ubuntu desktop, and I am now being nagged by the “pending update of snap store” message.  I don’t want snap store enabled, so I would like to turn it off.  The answer at [Pending Update of Snap Store](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412575/pending-update-of-snap-store/1412580#1412580) has instructions, and I can just turn it off in System Monitor.

But I have applications apparently installed by snap store – I see them when I do “snap list” at the command line.  My question is, if I turn it off will that affect the apps already installed?  According to the question at [Unable to update "Snap Store": cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has running apps (ubuntu-software)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411104/unable-to-update-snap-store-cannot-refresh-snap-store-snap-snap-store-ha) I may have trouble.

I don’t want to use snap to install applications, I prefer to use the command line.  Will permanently disabling it cause trouble with apps already installed?

Thanks very much.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412575/pending-update-of-snap-store/1412580#1412580

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The snap store is a graphical front end for installing applications, including snap applications. You can safely uninstall it. This will, in no way, affect other installed programs. You will still be fully able to manage your applications - both snap and APT - using the dedicated command line tools, `snap` and `apt` (or `apt-get`, `aptitude`, etc) respectively.