# After installation problems kworker/interrupts/snapdepencie-update-error

Tags: system-installation

I have this 3 problems see images please
Snap store update error
Interrupts
Kworker

[interrupts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W8Ne.jpg)
[kworker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otsOw.png)
[kworker1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNEol.png)
[kworker2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6kUJ.png)
[snapstore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxPsV.jpg)

---

[single-cpu-core-overload-unknown-funtions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W8Ne.jpg)

Interrupts can be related to the unavaiable firmware version for this pc, i cant manage to know the source of the problem fix/mask interrupt.

Kworker have more then 100 process and dependecies not just related to the cpu cores that overloads cores on 200% cpu single core usage.

Snapstore update error results in total failure from Ubuntu store if i uninstall and reinstall / kill / refresh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to update "Snap Store": cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has running apps (ubuntu-software)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411104/unable-to-update-snap-store-cannot-refresh-snap-store-snap-snap-store-ha)

Comment: 3 problems = 3 questions. Elaborate on your problems and do not let people wanting to help you to guess your problems. Indicate why the figures you show are problems for you. I did not see any. Help the people that try to help you.