# Unable to update "Snap Store" from Ubuntu software

Tags: 22.04, snap-store

I upgraded my Acer Nitro 5 to 22.04 and this error occurred when trying to update Snap Store:

[image: screenshot of errror]

> Unable to update "Snap Store":
> (null): cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has running apps (ubuntu-software), pids: xxxx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to update "Snap Store": cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has running apps (ubuntu-software)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411104/unable-to-update-snap-store-cannot-refresh-snap-store-snap-snap-store-ha)

Comment: Try `snap-store --quit`. Then `sudo snap refresh`. The snap-store cannot update itself while running.