# Software updating notificaton, 2 different responses on 2 different computers

Tags: updates

I have Ubuntu 22.04 on 2 computers at home.   One notifies me there is software to update every morning when I turn it on.   Then I go to the software updater and it says my software is up to date.  Every day.
On this other computer, it only notifies me every once in a while and then there is actually software that it updates.
Why is the one computer notifying me every day when there is really no software to update?   Is there some setting I have accidentally set?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to update "Snap Store": cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has running apps (ubuntu-software)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411104/unable-to-update-snap-store-cannot-refresh-snap-store-snap-snap-store-ha)

Answer (score -1):

open "software &updates" app

[image]

then clik the updates tab. Then change the ``when there are other updates'' menu setting.

Comment: I checked on both computers and they are both set the same in this setting so since they both behave differently I don't think that's it.  But this did remind me that I did install something different on that other computer.   I wish I could remember what it was, but it was some underlying software it wanted to install so that I could install some other software.  Maybe I'll remember what that was, but that was a difference that came to mind.  Thanks for your information.  I learned something.