Updating to Ubuntu 22.04 Unable to update Snapstore
Just updated to Ubuntu 22.04. Not without problems, though.
I use 2 monitors, but Ubuntu only recognizes one of them.
Tried to Snap update but does not work.

"Unable to update "Snapstore": (null): cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has running apps (snap-store), pids: 2570


Did you try rebooting?

Does this help : https://askubuntu.com/q/1411104/653727. It will update snap-store and remove that warning but the dual monitor problem is another question.
